# Angular 2 KeyboardEvent for keydown is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, keyboard-events, keydown

I'm trying to launch an keydown event that changes the keydown pressed to an comma. If you press some other not numeric value it sends an keydown event that  simulates the comma and the expect behavior is write an comma in the textbox. The problem is when it finish the second call( the comma one) it's doesn't write the comma. Anyone with some ideas about this?

Thanks.

```
<input type="text" (keydown)="validate($event)" />


validate(event) {

    if (!this.validatenumeric(event)) {
      event.preventDefault();

    } else {
        if(event.key!=","){
        event.preventDefault();
        var getterCode = { get: function () { return 188 } };
        var getsourceCapabilities = { get: function () { return event.sourceCapabilities } };
        var e = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
          altKey: false,
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true,
          code: "Comma",
          composed: true,
          ctrlKey: false,
          key: ",",
          detail: 0,
          location: 0,
          metaKey: false,
          repeat: false,
          shiftKey: false,
          view: window
        });

        Object.defineProperties(e, {

          which: getterCode,
          keyCode: getterCode,
          sourceCapabilities: getsourceCapabilities
        });

            this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input').dispatchEvent(e);

          }
        }
      }


 validatenumeric(key) {
    var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
    //comparing pressed keycodes
    if ((keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57)) {
      // 0-9 only
      return true;
    } else if ((keycode >= 96 && keycode <= 105)) {
      // 0-9 only
       return true;
    }
    else return false;

    return false;
  }
```

Some Update.. I think I could solve this. Instead trying to do another keydown.. I create an KeyUp and check if it's an comma.. Get where the cursor is and insert the comma in the position. Don't know if there is a simple way to do it :) Thanks to everyone

```
> <input type="text" (keydown)="validate($event)"
> (keyup)="validateUp($event)" />
> 
>   validateUp(event) {    let pos =
> this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input').selectionEnd;
>     if (event.key == ',' ) {
>       this.textValue = text.slice(0, pos) + event.key + text.slice(pos);
>       }   }
> 
> 
>   validateWithtDecimals(event) {
>     var text: string = this.textValue;
> 
> 
>     if (!this.validatenumeric(event, text, this.separator)) {
>       event.preventDefault();
>     }
>     else {
> 
>        if(event.key!=","){
>         event.preventDefault(); 
>       
>         var getterCode = { get: function () { return 188 } };
> 
>         var e = new KeyboardEvent("keyup", {
>           altKey: false,
>           bubbles: true,
>           cancelable: true,
>           code: "Comma",
>           composed: true,
>           ctrlKey: false,
>           key: ",",
>           detail: 0,
>           location: 0,
>           metaKey: false,
>           repeat: false,
>           shiftKey: false,
>           view: window
>         });
> 
>         Object.defineProperties(e, {
>           which: getterCode,
>           keyCode: getterCode,
>         });
> 
>         this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input').dispatchEvent(e);
>       }
>     }   }
```

Comment: Do you need just to filter numeric format or something else?

Comment: I need to filter more things. The thing is convert the dot from numeric pad to an comma.

Comment: Why don't you use [(ngModel)]="myValue", and in ts in property setter filter the user input? It would much clear then using keyboard events.

Comment: The value can already have "dot". it's why I need to change that dot to comma.. Don't understand why it doesn't write the comma when I execute the event.. the event.preventDefault() is not called.

Comment: how would your code work if you paste value to the input with ctrl+v

Comment: What? I don't copy any value..

Comment: Not, you but user of your form. What if user won't type to the input, but paste some value? You want get keydown event

Comment: I believe that the user will be always tying. If not then he should paste the value in the correct format.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to use binding instead of keyboard events:

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="valueToValidate" />
```

In **component.ts**:

```
 private _value = '';
 get valueToValidate(): string {
     return this._value;
 }
 set valueToValidate(value: string) {
     value = value.replace('.',',');
     // your validation here
     this._value = value;
 }
```